# Поиск чисел в string

Tags: c#

Решаю задачу:

> В ЕГЭ по математике было решено не давать задач, в которых используются числа, большие 5, например, 6, 10 и т.п. (они теперь считаются трудными и не обязательными для изучения). Вводится уравнение. Требуется определить, можно ли его давать в ЕГЭ (в уравнении могут присутствовать любые символы-нецифры, а также натуральные числа).

моё решение:

```
string @int = string.Empty;

foreach (char ch in s.ToCharArray())
    if (char.IsDigit(ch))
    {
        @int += ch.ToString();
        int result = int.Parse(@int);
        if (result > 5)
            {
            ege = false;
            }
        @int = string.Empty;
    }
```

Этот код считывает число (однозначное) из string и проверяет больше 5 оно или нет. Как его исправить, чтобы он мог считать любые числа, разделённые любыми символами, и двузначное и пятизначное (и т. д.)?

Comment: так не обнуляйте `@int = string.Empty;`

Comment: @tym32167 Если не обнулять, то если ввести `2x+3=5` то он напишет, что число = 235

Comment: А вы что ожидаете получить, когда вводите `2x+3=5`?

Comment: @Андрей Числа разделяются любыми знаками из таблицы ASCII, забыл упомянуть.

Comment: Ок, а что получить-то ожидаете?

Comment: @Андрей Это задача на сайте informatics.mccme.ru, я её не могу решить: `В ЕГЭ по математике было решено не давать задач, в которых используются числа, большие 5, например, 6, 10 и т.п. (они теперь считаются трудными и не обязательными для изучения). Вводится уравнение. Требуется определить, можно ли его давать в ЕГЭ (в уравнении могут присутствовать любые символы-нецифры, а также натуральные числа).`

Comment: Ага, ну значит один вариант недопустимого числа вы проверяете, другой вариант - проверить, нет ли во введенной строке двух или более идущих подряд цифр. Напишите ещё один цикл, который будет проверять два идущих подряд символа, сами цифры при этом значения не имеют

Comment: @Андрей Я не понимаю куда цикл вставить, и как проверить 2 подряд идущие цифры, как вообще понять что они подряд идут? Я хороший тормоз.

Comment: @Андрей `сами цифры при этом значения не имеют` только если нет варианта `00001` :)

Comment: @tym32167. ну это было бы странно, конечно, но с точки зрения программиста вы правы. Опубликовал свое решение с одним циклом с проверкой минимального достаточного условия невалидности. Ну и без прочих нагрузок в виде `Parse`, который тут не нужен в общем-то

Comment: @Андрей это же алгоритмическая задачка, там наверняка есть тесты для варианта `0001`. Ну и, как ни печально признавать, ваш вариант действительно быстрее :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Набросал на скорую руку вариант со вложенным циклом

```
public bool IsValidString(string str)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) return true;

    for (var i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        if (char.IsDigit(str[i]))
        {
            for (var j = i + 1; j <= str.Length; j++)
            {
                if ((j == str.Length) || !char.IsDigit(str[j]))
                {                       
                    int n;
                    if (int.TryParse(str.Substring(i, j - i), out n))
                    {
                        if (n > 5) return false;
                    }
                    else return false;              
                    i = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

также можно попробовать вариант с регуляркой, но регулярка будет медленней работать.

UPD. Чуть поправил алгоритм

Comment: Один вопрос остался, я разобрался, спасибо, но VS пишет, что `Для нестатического поля/метода/свойства требуется ссылка на объект`

Comment: Где пишет? На какую строку ругается? Как это относится к текущему вопросу? Я ж не гадалка, я ваш код не вижу :)

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/vve1p - Это ошибка

Comment: Ну поставьте `public static bool IsValidString(string str)` и всего делов

Comment: Ясно, спасибо!)

Comment: @OsidDev Только обязательно разберистесь в самом алгоритме, не стоит просто копипастить - так не научитесь решать задачи.

Comment: Да, я разобрался. Всё-таки какое-то значение умудряется выдать в программу ошибку... На сайте informatics.mccme.ru... Пишет `Ошибка во время выполнения программы`

Comment: Возможно нужна проверка на пустую строку и Null вначале метода. Обновил ответ

Comment: Если-бы была бы пустая строка, то тогда программа выдала бы YES без всяких ошибок...

Comment: Значит строку надо проверить на  null

Comment: Загрузил, сервер протестил, ошибка та же самая, ничего не изменилось. (

Comment: Я сделал! Через t`ry{}catch{}` обработал всё и вставил `return false;` Теперь всё правильно.

Comment: Ничего не правильно, мы не предусмотрели переполнение числа при парсинге. Обновил алгоритм, проверяйте

Comment: Тоже работает! Огромное вам спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Простой алгоритм с одним циклом и без индексов

```
static IEnumerable<int> ParseNumbers(string source)
{
    var currentNumber = new StringBuilder();
    source += "!"; //Добавляем не цифру в конец строки, чтобы строка гарантированно оканчивалась не цифрой
    foreach (var ch in source)
    {
        if (char.IsDigit(ch))
            currentNumber.Append(ch);
        else
        {
            if (currentNumber.Length > 0)
            {
                yield return int.Parse(currentNumber.ToString());
                currentNumber.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что он должен вернуть?

Comment: Перечисление всех чисел в строке foreach (var number in ParseNumbers("1r2efr234fgeg456"))
                Console.WriteLine(number);
Если нужно то IEnumerable можно преобразовать в список или в массив

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что сложение строки с символом в цикле делает время работы алгоритма квадратичным? Ну, и, как было в моем алгоритме, у вас нет обработки больших чисел (если в строке будет число, которое не укладывается в Int32)

Comment: Вместо int можно использовать long и другие типы данных, это не так важно. Квадратичным да, чтобы сделать его не квадратичным нужно использовать StringBuilder, но даже в таком виде это тоже не так важно, так как максимально в int 9 символов. Кстати ваш алгоритм точно так же не будет работать, так как вы используете int.TryParse но еще у вас число большее чем Int32 не будет распознаваться как число, а не вызовет соответствующее исключение.

Comment: Мой алгоритм как раз сработает верно, так как если число сильно большое - то оно точно больше 5. Тут и исключений не надо никаких, так как в условии нет ограничения на длину числа в строке. Мой алгоритм ещё и отработает за линейное время. Ну, ок, почти линейное, там ещё множитель от количества чисел будет :) Н это точно быстрее вашего варианта, так как вы для каждой цифры большого числа конкатенируете строку. Я имею ввиду, ваш вариант тоже работчий, просто он медленней моего, так как конкатенировать строку для каждой цифры числа довольно расточительно

Comment: Причем тут 5 если TryParse возвращает false? Но вы меня уговорили, чтобы вам не резала взгляд конкатинация строк я ее поправлю.

Comment: `Причем тут 5 если TryParse возвращает false?` В моем случае оно вернет false только если число в строке больше int.maxvalue, что само по себе больше 5, потому я и возвращаю false :)

Comment: Ну если задача стоит найти все числа больше 5 то да, но в проектах я бы такой код использовать бы побоялся

Answer (score 1):

Вот более оптимальный алгоритм, который проверяет только достаточное условие невалидного выражения: просматриваем строку, если встречаем цифру - проверяем не больше ли она 5, если так - возврат false, иначе если она больше 0 смотрим следующий символ и если он цифровой - возврат false. Если цикл завершился успешно - возврат true.

```
static bool IsValid(string s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; ++i)
        if (char.IsDigit(s[i]))
        {
            if (s[i] > '5') return false;
            if (s[i] > '0' && i + 1 < s.Length && char.IsDigit(s[i + 1])) return false;
        }
    return true;
}
```

Проверяем:

```
Console.WriteLine(IsValid("2x+1=3"));   // True
Console.WriteLine(IsValid("4x+6=3"));   // False
Console.WriteLine(IsValid("2x+4=10"));  // False
Console.WriteLine(IsValid("20x+1=3"));  // False
Console.WriteLine(IsValid("2x+01=3"));  // True
Console.WriteLine(IsValid("2x+1=03"));  // True
Console.WriteLine(IsValid("2x+1=003")); // True
Console.WriteLine(IsValid("2x+1=030")); // False
```